# Difficulties in create a confusion matrix in R for Yes or No

Tags: r, regression, logistic-regression, confusion-matrix, rstudio

I am new to regression and confusion matrix and trying to create a confusion matrix from logistic binary regression model. I am trying to create a confusion matrix from Yes or No values from the column, Survived. I am using a default dataset, Titanic. I received an error when trying to perform Confusion Matrix

The dataset, Titanic content is found here.
[Titanic Content](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B6FXO.png)

Here is the R code below.

```
example$Class<- as.factor(example$Class)
example$Sex<- as.factor(example$Sex)
example$Age<- as.factor(example$Age)
example$Survived<- as.factor(example$Survived)

trainRowNum <- createDataPartition(example$Survived, #The outcome variable
#proportion of example to form the training set
p=0.3,
#Don't store the result in a list
list=FALSE);
# Step 2: Create the training mydataset
trainData <- example[trainRowNum,] 
# Step 3: Create the test mydataset
testData <- example[-trainRowNum,]

mod.surv.lg <- glm(Survived~., family=binomial(), data=trainData);
#Provide a summary of the model
summary(mod.surv.lg)

p <- predict(mod.surv.lg, testData,type="response")
p_class <- ifelse(p > 0.5,"Yes","No")
table(p_class)
p_class
table(p_class, testData[["Survived"]])
confusionMatrix(p_class, testData$Survived);
```

I received an error when performing confusionMatrix function

```
[1] No  Yes
<0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)
Warning message:
In Ops.factor(predictedScores, threshold) : ‘<’ not meaningful for factors
```

Comment: did you try to assign as.factor() https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30002013/error-in-confusion-matrix-the-data-and-reference-factors-must-have-the-same-nu

Comment: @Peter, I did try as.factor and it worked but I am unable to get the accuracy, sensitivity and specificity. How to achieve that?

Comment: The code cannot reproduce the full programm, so I'm not able to check back

Comment: @peter, so my code in confusion matrix is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You didn't provide your dataset so I used the library `titanic`. I tried to make the data similar to the one you have, but there might be differences (btw this is why you should provide a reproducible code, preferably).

```
# Added to make this a reproducible code
library(caret)
library(titanic)

# select columns used by OP
# caution: different column name than OP for "Class"
example <- titanic_train[,c('Pclass','Sex', 'Age', 'Survived')]
# remove rows with NAs
example <- example[complete.cases(example),]
# changing class to "Yes"/"No" instead of 1/0 in this version of titanic data to make it like OP's data
example$Survived <- ifelse(example$Survived==1,"Yes","No")

# not needed
#example$Class<- as.factor(example$Pclass)
#example$Sex<- as.factor(example$Sex)
# this was an error, age should be a numerical variable
#example$Age<- as.factor(example$Age)

example$Survived<- as.factor(example$Survived)

trainRowNum <- createDataPartition(example$Survived, #The outcome variable
                                   #proportion of example to form the training set
                                   p=0.3,
                                   #Don't store the result in a list
                                   list=FALSE)

# Step 2: Create the training mydataset
trainData <- example[trainRowNum,] 
# Step 3: Create the test mydataset
testData <- example[-trainRowNum,]

mod.surv.lg <- glm(Survived~., family=binomial(), data=trainData)
p <- predict(mod.surv.lg, testData,type="response")

p_class <- ifelse(p > 0.5,"Yes","No")

# ensure compatible factors in both the gold and predicted vectors:
all.as.factors <- as.factor(c(as.character(testData$Survived),as.character(p_class)))
gold.as.factors <- head(all.as.factors, length(testData$Survived))
pred.as.factors <- tail(all.as.factors, length(p_class))

confusionMatrix(p_class, testData$Survived)
```

I think the problem was the missing `as.factors` for `p_class`. Factors in R are not very intuitive, I still get confused frequently myself.

Comment: it still produces the same error, [1] No  Yes
<0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)
Warning message:
In Ops.factor(predictedScores, threshold) : ‘<’ not meaningful for factors

Comment: @painintheass did you try with the data I used from the titanic R library? If not, it's probably related to the format of the data that you use. Without it I can't debug.

Comment: yes I did try the data from the titanic R library.  Error in model.frame.default(Terms, newdata, na.action = na.action, xlev = object$xlevels) : 
  factor Class has new levels 3rd
> 
> p_class <- as.factor(ifelse(p > 0.5,"Yes","No"))
Error in ifelse(p > 0.5, "Yes", "No") : object 'p' not found
> 
> confusionMatrix(p_class, testData$Survived)
Error in confusionMatrix(p_class, testData$Survived) : 
  object 'p_class' not found
In addition: Warning message:
In Ops.factor(predictedScores, threshold) : ‘<’ not meaningful for factors

Comment: @painintheass this is a bit strange because my code works in recent versions of R, you can try it in the browser [here](https://rdrr.io/snippets/). So I suspect that the issue has something to do with the version of R that you're using. Anyway I edited my code to try to solve the factor issue, but it's hard to know if it works since I don't have the bug myself.